# Oracle Apex change row color

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

Using below, I'm able to change the background color the column in APEX classic report.

```
#static_id td[headers="TOTAL"]{background: rgb(164, 164, 164) !important;}
```

How do I change the background color of a row? In this case, I want to change the color of my last row (Totals)
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jjsd.png)

Answer (score 5):

I don't have Apex 5.1 any more; tested this on apex.oracle.com which currently runs Apex 22.1.0.

Classic report query:

```
select 1 rn, ename, job, sal
  from emp 
  where deptno = 10
union all
select 2 rn, 'Total', null, sum(sal)
  from emp
  where deptno = 10
order by rn, ename
```

Create a dynamic action:

- Name: da_total_bkg_col
- Event: After Refresh
- Selection Type: Region
- Region: Report 1 (that's the name of region that contains that query)

True condition:

- Action: Execute JavaScript code
- Code:

  ```
   $('td[headers="ENAME"]').each(function() {
     if ( $(this).text() === 'Total' ) {
       $(this).closest('tr').find('td').css({"background-color":"red"});
    }
  });
  ```
- Affected elements: type = Region, Region = Report1
- Fire on initialization: yes

Run the page; the result looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here n=column number, u can simply put this CSS  code in inline section

```
td:nth-child(n)
{
background-color: blue;
}
```